# Echo short description for related products

Tags: php, magento

Is there a way to echo the short description foreach related product?

I've tried to use this code but it doesn't display the description of each product:

```
<?php echo nl2br($this->getProduct()->getDescription()) ?>
```

also

```
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_item, nl2br($_item->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?>
```

Is there a way to do this for related products? If anyone knows please point me in the right direction.

```
<?php if($this->getItems()->getSize()): ?>
<div class="block block-related">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Related Products') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <p class="block-subtitle"><?php echo $this->__('Check items to add to the cart or add to your wishlist') ?>&nbsp;<br /></p>
        <div class="form-horizontal">
        <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
             <div class="control-group">
                    <label for="related-checkbox<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" class="control-label">
                        <a class="fancybox static-thumbs pull-left" href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'small_image')->resize(500, 450); ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" ><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'small_image')->resize(135, 135) ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" /></a>
                    </label>
<div class="controls">
<label class="checkbox">
        <?php if(!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable()): ?>
            <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox related-checkbox" id="related-checkbox<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" name="related_products[]" value="<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" />
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_item) ?>" class="pull-right" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?>" rel="tooltip"><span class="icon-check"></span></a>

<p class="product-name span6">
 <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product-title"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?></a>
 <br />
<?php echo nl2br($this->getProduct($_item)->getDescription()) ?>
</p>
<form action="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>" method="post">
<fieldset>
  <label class="product-name"><?php echo $this->__('Quantity:'); ?></label>
  <select name="qty" class="span1">
  <?php $i = 1 ?>
  <?php do { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i?>">
      <?php echo $i?>
      <?php $i++ ?>
    </option>
    <?php } while ($i <= (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_item)->getMaxSaleQty()) ?>
</select>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<button class="btn btn-danger" data-loading-text="PLease wait..."><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></button>
<span id='ajax_loader' style='display:none'><img src='<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/opc-ajax-loader.gif')?>'/></span>            
</fieldset>
</form>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-related') ?>
</label>
</div>
    </div>
    <hr />
        <?php endforeach ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you have a list of products? If so, show us some code where your products are stored in.

Comment: @CE_REAL See code above^ is a list displaying related items on a CMS page I just need to show the description foreach item in the list...

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of code which does not make it much clearer. Are the related projects in a different list/array? Or are they just retrieved using a function of the product, like $porduct->getRelatedProduct()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `nl2br($this->getProduct($_item)->getShortDescription())` ?

It might be that the value for short description isn't loaded for related products by default. You could try to do a `$_item->load($_item->getId())` and then use `$_item->getShortDescription()`.

Comment: Done: <?php $_item->getShortDescription() ?> Thankyou so much dude!

Answer (score 0):

after TRYING `$_item->load($_item->getId())` and echoing the shortDescription, you should look for the Collection where the related products are loaded. In this collection the attribute `short_description` is not loaded with.

If you load every product, you make a lot of queries to the database which will cost a lot of performance. This is not needed. The alternative is:

```
$relatedProductCollection->addAttributeToSelect('short_description');
```

The question is to find the `$relatedProductCollection`.

UPDATE:
I dug into the code (Reference is v. 1.7.0.2):

```
// app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Related.php:61
$this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($this->_itemCollection);

// app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Abstract.php:410
$collection
->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())

// app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Config.php:260
$this->getAttributesUsedInProductListing()
```

This should be interpreted as: When the "related products" are loaded, all attributes are loaded, which are used in the product listing as well. The problem might be: short_desciption is loaded by default. So remove the `load()` call and check, wether the attribute `short_description` is "Used in Product Listing". If this is set to yes, My interpretation is wrong.

None the less, the solution by loading every product is crap.

EDIT:
I have added the following line to Related.php

```
$this->_itemCollection = $product->getRelatedProductCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('required_options') 
->addAttributeToSelect('short_description') 
->setPositionOrder() 
->addStoreFilter()
```

And using this line does echo a descrtiption foreach product but it is the Same description getProduct()->getDescription()) ?>

You need to `<?php echo ($this->getProduct()->getShortDescription()) ?>`

But editing the core code is a bad way to change the magento behaviour as well. Here is described how to rewrite a block, but I don't think this is necessary. http://prattski.com/2010/06/24/magento-overriding-core-files-blocks-models-resources-controllers/

Comment: @Fabial Blechschmidt I get this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function addAttributeToSelect() on a non-object in

Comment: You aren't experienced with magento, are you? This was sample code. Your task is, to load the object as @Lucasmus described. But the problem is: You load every object as a single item and for every product you fire a SQL-query. This is wasting of resources. When this way works. This means, the collection which is used to load the products doesn't load the EAV attribute short_description... edited the answer

Comment: I moved the file in to local folder, yes I am very new to Magento which is why I asked for some assistance. I'm not sure if the method that I have used is correct or if I should change it?

Comment: I do all file edits in the local code pool I am aware that I should never edit the core file system.

Comment: good thing, you know a very important basic! :-) The problem with overwriting a core-model/block with this method is, that after an update, the old (local) code is used, instead of the new. So the better alternative is, to rewrite the block, as I linked in the answer, so only one method is overwritten and the rest is inherited. If you update magento (and th original block class), only your changes are used and not the whole old class

Comment: @FabianBlechscmidt Thanks for your help and advice. My knowledge is growing with each problem or customisation. Would you say that using the code snippet in the answer is bad practice? The reason I ask is that I only wish to have the short_description echoed on my custom CMS pages.

Comment: Yes. Loading each product in a loop is bad practice. You can have this by just adding the attribute to the select. The problem is, you have to find the right place, to get the collection class. As I wrote above, I think the related products are loaded with the attributes defined for the product-listing (aka category page), so it should be easy to add the short description to the collection in the backend.